# How to get latest id only from database using LINQ in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

```
Id | StName | Subject  | 
 1 |  Tom   |  Math    |
 2 |  Jerry |  Science |
```

I am new in LINQ and I am trying to get only `Id` of `StName` *Jerry* from database using LINQ but I couldn't.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<StudentModel> GetStudentId()
{
    var id = _context.StudentModel.OrderBy(a => a.Id).ToList();
    return(id);
}
```

but I got all the data. I want to get the latest recorded id (only id).

Comment: I want to get newly recorded id (only id)

Comment: Yes it would return you a `Id` only. Have look and let me know if that works as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you're getting a list of *all* records in your database table. You only want the *first one* when ordered by the Id *in descending order*.

```
[HttpGet]
public int GetStudentId()
{
    var latestStudentRecord = _context.StudentModel
        .OrderByDescending(a => a.Id)
        .First();

    // return only the Id property of the latest record
    return latestStudentRecord.Id;
}
```

Note, this will only work if your Id's are sequential, and it's guaranteed that the "latest" record will always have the highest Id value.

Later on, you might want to swap `First()` to `FirstOrDefault()`, in the case where your table has no records.

The method signature has been changed to return only an int rather than the whole list.

Answer (score 2):

You could try below code.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public int GetStudentId()
{
    var id = _context.StudentModel.OrderByDescending(a => a.Id).FirstOrDefault();
     return id.Id;
}
```

Also You could write some like below:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public int GetStudentId()
{
     var id = _context.StudentModel.Max(a => a.Id).FirstOrDefault();
     return id.Id;
}
```

**Note:** The things you have to do is, need to filter max or top entry of database entity then return it. I have done that as well.

Comment: public IEnumerable<StudentModel> GetStudentId() when i use this then I get error in return(id.Id), error: Cannot implicitly convert type  int to System.Collections.Generic....................

Comment: Updated the answer though you needn't to return `IEnumerable<StudentModel>` you want a single id right?

Comment: Yeah, i need newly recorded id ( only single id), your code is fine when I use public int GetStudentId() {
    var id = _context.StudentModel.OrderByDescending(a => a.Id).FirstOrDefault();
     return id.Id;
}

Comment: Yes!!  Your code is also the same. Then what if I want in return only string data instead of Id?   ( StName=Tom )

Answer (score 0):

Change method to return same type as your Id, then fetch just first item of the collection and return its property Id.

This should be the case.

```
public int GetStudentId()
{
    var student = _context.StudentModel.OrderBy(a => a.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    return student.Id;
}
```